# Stretch a sub nav bar across the width of the page on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, nav

I have a navigation menu on a wordpress website with a sub menu on certain elements.

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav_container">
        <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-page-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-page-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-36">
                <a href="...">Cottages</a>

                <div id="sub_menu_container">
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-46 current_page_item menu-item-51">
                            <a href="...">Cottage 1</a>
                        </li>

                        <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50">
                            <a href="...">Cottage 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>

            ...more li elements etc 
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The menu elements are centred on the page, but the background of the nav stretches across the page width.

The problem I am having is the design of the nav is such that the sub menu elements appear directly under the first nav, with the menu elements directly under the parent menu element, but with the background also stretching across the width of the page.

Given that I am using relative and absolute positions and given that the main menu elements are centred on the page, while their background stretches across the width of the page (i do this using a div with a certain width) the sub menu, when it has a width of 100% is only ever the width of the div that is centring the main menu elements.

It's probably also worth saying that I managed to achieve the desired look without using position relative and absolute but it meant the sub menu was not 'attached' to the main menu and the mouse left the hover area when trying to reach the sub menu, which then disappeared, so it couldn't be reached before it disappeared.

I have attached an image of what I am after to make it more clear and I also attach below the current css I have.

```
.nav_container
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;

    width: 1055px;
}

nav
{
    width: 100%;
height: 40px;

    background: #685c53;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px #37332e;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px #37332e;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px #37332e;  

    position: relative;
}

nav ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    display: inline;
}

nav li
{
    display: inline;
    padding: 8px 9px;
}

#sub_menu_container
{
    display: none;

    float: left;

    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;

    padding-top: 40px;

    width: 100%;
}

nav ul .sub-menu
{
    text-align: center;

    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;

    background: #b3a797;

    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px #685c53;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px #685c53;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px #685c53;  
}

nav ul li:hover > #sub_menu_container
{
    display: block;
}

.sub-menu li 
{
    display: inline-block;

    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;

    padding-left: 10px;

    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[image: Nav]

**Update**
Having changed my css to:

I then get back to the original problem, in that the background highlights my problem that the sub menu must be 'attached' to the element from which you mouse hover over so you can move your mouse from the main menu to the sub menu without the menu disappearing.

[image: Updated Nav]

Answer (score 0):

make the following changes. I think this is what you were looking for.

```
#sub_menu_container
{
display: none;
float: left;
position: absolute; 
top:;
left:0px;
padding-top: 10px;
width: 100%;
background-color:black;/*this is for testing purposes*/
}
```

please comment for further info or telling me if this is what you wanted. Hope it helps Pippa Rose Smith. thanks

Comment: Actually, from my initial delight, I realised that gets me back to the same problem I had before. I will update the question with an updated image so you can see the problem.

Comment: I've updated the questions. As you can see, I can't get the sub nav to start directly under the main nav background, it has to start directly under the main nav text so I can get from one to the other without the sub menu disappearing. Also, the text needs to be under the main nav element which it came from

Comment: No, well it's a wordpress website, but there's nothing affecting the code it's pure html and css

Comment: I think the problem is how do you use the hover display:none, display:block effect when the two elements don't touch and one of the elements has a background, and it is not an image so you can't use margins or padding.

Comment: @PippaRoseSmith is the navbar moving when hovered a problem

Comment: @PippaRoseSmith you are right you need to use display:block

Comment: @PippaRoseSmith I am very sorry but I am not 100% sure on what needs to be edited or what the problem is can you try to post an image with **annotations** of what you want to be done.

Comment: You see in my second picture? The top of the sub nav bar is touching the text in the main nav bar. 

I want it to be a bit lower. 

But it needs to be touching the text because otherwise the hover effect will not work because when you move your mouse out of the hover area, if it is not on the sub menu, the sub menu disappears.

Comment: @PippaRoseSmith what browser are you using

Comment: @PippaRoseSmith have you seen the navbar on any other website before

Answer (score 0):

I believe having the *unordered list* and the *sub-menu container* equal rather than one nested in the other would simplify things. Here's a full example of how I would do it, note *#sub*.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Cheeses
      <div id='sub'></div>
      <ul>
        <li>Opt1</li>
        <li>Opt2</li>
        <li>Opt3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Paper clips
      <div id='sub'></div>
      <ul>
        <li>Opt1</li>
        <li>Opt2</li>
        <li>Opt3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Swords
      <div id='sub'></div>
      <ul>
        <li>Opt1</li>
        <li>Opt2</li>
        <li>Opt3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

nav{
  background:green;
}

ul{
  display:flex;
}

li{
  display:inline;
  margin:auto;
}

li>ul{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
}

li:hover>ul{
  display:inline;
}

#sub{
  background:blue;
  display:none;
  height:1.5em;
  left:0px;
  position:absolute;
  width:100vw;
}

li:hover>#sub{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a bit constrained by the wordpress nav bar html layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
.sub-menu li 
{
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-left: 10px;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Please comment back if this is not what you would like. Check fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/gq2fM/